# Cloudfront removes the header - Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, private

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront

I am using a custom origin that adds a `Cache-control: no-store, no-cache, max-age=0, private` header to the response. I can see it when navigating to the origin.

However, when navigating to cloudfront site, the Cache-control header is totally gone. I've set `Object caching` to `Use Origin Cache Headers` in behaviours, which should make it leave the `Cache-control` header alone, but for some reason, it's always stripping it.

Are there any other settings that might influence this or is there something I don't know about Cloudfront that's causing this behaviour?

Comment: CloudFront does not remove this header, regardless of cache behavior configuration (Use Origin Cache Headers tells CloudFront to *honor* it, otherwise it's ignored for CloudFront caching purposes, but it's returned to the browser in either case).  Check the `Age:` and `X-Cache:` headers in the responses.  Are you perhaps seeing responses that CloudFront cached before the origin was configured as you describe?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: It doesn't seem like that, I'm getting `X-Cache:Miss from cloudfront` in the response.

Comment: Well, that looks fresh (assuming your browser is really fetching it, not showing you a locally cached version -- do you get a fresh `X-Amz-Cf-Id` with each response?).  I just  now changed the response headers on [my test site](https://cloudfront.sqlbot.net) from its usual response of `Cache-Control: private, no-cache, no-store` to match your version, and still it seems to do the right thing (I see it in Chrome).  My site is also config'ed to "Use Origin Cache Headers."  Do you see the header when you request my page?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: Yes, I get a new `X-Amz-Cf-Id` with each response. I can see the correct `Cache-Control` header in the response from your site in my Chrome as well.

Comment: That *should* tend to rule out CloudFront removing the header -- in fact, I'm not aware of any way to configure CloudFront to remove the header, even if you wanted to.  Can you share the hostname of your distribution and origin so I can take a look at the responses?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot: I had to redeploy the whole application again. And with preconfigured Cloudfront, now the `Cache-Control` header is being passed through correctly. Can't quite pin on what was the issue here. Anyway, thanks for all your help and time :)